# Convert type<T> to bool, what's wrong?

Tags: c++, class, generics, type-conversion

the following code doesn't work as expected:

```
template<class T>
bool any(const Matrix<T> &matrix) {
    int matrix_height = matrix.height();
    int matrix_width = matrix.width();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix_width; j++) {
            if (matrix(i, j) == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For a matrix like {-1,0,0,0} there is a member -1 which is true so it's supposed to return true but it returns false. Am I converting T value to bool in a wrong way?

Comment: Why not just do `if (matrix(i, j) != T{})`?

Comment: what is T{}? may you explain

Comment: why not just do `if (matrix(i, j))`?

Comment: @smith it default constructs an object of type `T`.

Comment: Thanks, may someone explain why is this I always learnt that if (something== true) is equal to if (something)

Comment: Because it is `true` that `true == true`, and `false` that `false == true`.

Comment: `int i = 3; if (i) cout << "i is truthy\n"; else cout << "i is falsy\n"; if (i == true) cout << "i==true is true\n"; else cout << "i==true is false\n";`

Answer (score 0):

To check if a condition is truth(y), you use `if(condition)`. This evaluates an expression to boolean. So `if(7)` evaluates as `if((bool)7)`, which is indeed true. On the other hand,

```
if(7 == true)
```

evaluates a numerical equality, up-casting `true` to integer, and comparing that to `7`. In most implementation I'm familiar with (all?) `true == 1`, so this evaluates to `7 == 1`. The only number that will yield true here (usually) is `1`.